# Authenticated twitter requests using only access token

Tags: twitter, oauth-1.0a

I'm trying to authenticate twitter requests on behalf of another user.
Basically I have 3 things:

- Twitter ID
- oauth_token (Access token)
- oauth_secret (Access token secret)

From everything i can see in the docs, i also need the consumer key and secret (API_KEY, API_SECRET) to authenticate, but unfortunately i do not have access to those.

Is there a way to make requests using only oauth token and secret?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No. The OAuth token and secret are directly associated with the user, and the Consumer Key for the application that the user logged in with. They are not useful without the Consumer Key (also known as API Key).